# How to mapping object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

i'm trying to make reminder. and i try to make that the reminder is send notification with the selected date and time. but i encounter an error where when i try to map the object. [image: this is the error and got redline] Can anyone help me why the 'time', 'title' and 'description' is error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.data()` to get the data from your `DocumentSnapshot`.

Update your code to this:

```dart
if (element.data.data()['from_uid'] == userId) {
  var reminder = {
    'time' : element.data.data()['time'],
    'title' : element.data.data()['title'],
    'description' : element.data.data()['description'],
  };
  DateTime date = (element.data.data()['time']).toDate();
}
```

Comment: i try to follow your instruction but getting error with .data()